# CheckBox Not Binding in PartialView AJAX PostBack

Tags: jquery, checkbox, ajaxform, ajax.beginform, checkboxfor

I have a form with a field and a checkbox in an Ajax Form on a Modal Popup,  When the user enters the data in the textbox and presses submit the values are posted and the Modal is closed. However if the user enters a value in the textbox and then checks the the checkbox the form will submit and the view will return to the modal on this time if the checkbox is checked I need to leave the form so that the user can submit another entry.  The issue is that the textbox maintains its state, which is what I want and so does the Checkbox, but, the Underlying value of the checkbox switches back to false even though the checkbox is still checked...
 A little stumped.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveValues", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions()
{   HttpMethod = "Post",
OnComplete = "ChkForCheckBox();"
}))
{ 
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DDate)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Dupe)
<button type="submit" >Save</button>
}
```

and in the Controller.

```
public void SaveValues( string DDate, bool Dupe)
{
   var rslt = repo.Post(DDate);
}
```

The JS.

```
 function ChkForCheckBox(){
    var rslt = $('#Dupe').prop('checked');
    if(!rslt){
     //Close Modal
}
}
```

However after the Ajax Post the CheckBox is still checked but the JS Script Check shows false?  If I comment out the CloseModal and look through the code the Value is set to False?   but if I post again it comes through as true? 
Verifying the ChkForCheckBox() again and it shows false.....
I'm missing something.

Comment: I believe I solved it but still not sure why. if I add a class to the checkbox and do the exact same .prop('checked') to the class it works as expected, I guess it has something to do with the way the CheckBoxFor() works.

Comment: So when you post the second time (after posting once with the checkbox checked) is the value on the controller true or false?

Comment: if the Checkbox is checked, The Value that gets posted back in the Second Post is True, but if I interogate the Checkbox using on Jquery and it's ID, it returns false.  Even the Source shows that its false.

Answer (score 0):

Your check is showing false because the `CheckBoxFor()` HTML helper also generates a hidden input. This is so the value is still posted even if the checkbox is not checked. Your check must be simply finding the hidden input value instead of the checkbox's value.

Comment: I believe you right but the strange part is that the subsequent posts have the value as being true even though the hiddenfield is false.

Comment: As long as the checkbox is checked, it's value will take precedence over whatever value the hidden field holds